# Android Java Get All Backround Running Apps Or Services

Tags: java, android, hibernate, kill-process, taskkill

My Goal is very simple. I am Developing An App killer(Hibernator).
I Want to make same as "Hibernator.apk", it's Package name is "com.tafayor.hibernator".
What it does that It iterate All background apps or Services. and then It Hibernate All one by One.
It also ask Accessibility permissions once pr day.

My Requirements are below.

1. Get all background running apps or Services.(not my App).
2. Or A funtion to detect an app which is running in background (not my app nor in recent apps) by package name.
3. Completely Suspend (hibernate) app by package name.

I have tried.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) {
  if(runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName.equals("com.the.app.you.are.looking.for")) {
    // Do your stuff here.
  }
}
```

And

```
public static boolean isForeground(Context ctx, String myPackage){
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1); 

    ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage)) {
        return true;
    }       
    return false;
}
```

But it Shows only my app.

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of the security rules that prevent you from doing this?

Comment: There are many apps on playstore that hibernate ruuning apps to save battery life.

Comment: "But it Shows only my app" -- correct. Those techniques were locked down years ago, to protect against malware. "It also ask Accessibility permissions once pr day" -- you may be working with a piece of malware, such as [this one](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/07/new-bank-fraud-malware-called-vultur-infects-thousands-of-devices/). This is why [Google is going to put limits on what apps can use accessibility services](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-trying-limit-apps-accessibility-service/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) instead `ActivityManager` or `AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcesses()` . Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/>` in your Manifest file.
Also give usage access permission to your app . Hope this answer give you a clue , use your desired logic.

[image]
[image]